# How to use column alias in where clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cross-join

[image]

I'm trying to remove all lines that have `productRef = productAssociated`.
I tried the query below, but the last line doesn't work.

What's going wrong?

```
SELECT date, transaction.transactionId, 
       ref.productSKU as productRef, 
       associated.productSKU as productAssociated, 
       ARRAY_LENGTH(hits.product) as nbProducts
FROM `dl-recommendation-engine.NDA_CHANEL_137002018.ga_sessions_*` as session,
     UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
     UNNEST(hits.product) as ref,
     UNNEST(hits.product) as associated
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20191122' AND '20191202' AND
      hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL AND
     ARRAY_LENGTH(hits.product) > 2 AND
     productAssociated != productRef
```

Comment: For reference, see [Problems with Column Aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html): "Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use table aliases in the `where` clause.

Instead, just use the expressions:

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20191122' AND '20191202' AND
      hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL AND
      ARRAY_LENGTH(hits.product) > 2 AND
      associated.productSKU <> ref.productSKU
```